# Is my rsync backup method safe?

Tags: backup, rsync, data-loss

I made a very simple backup script using `rsync` that backs up some folders to an USB stick. This is just for quick daily backups.

The command is

```
rsync -av --delete
```

followed by `--exclude` options and the paths.

But now it occurred to me that this is possibly not safe:
What happens if my hard drive gets corrupted, and some files can not be read anymore? Will `rsync` delete the files on the stick if it can't read the source?
Or more generally: Is there any scenario other than "me deleting the files on my hard drive" that will lead to deletion of the files on the USB stick?

Comment: why you don't use a real backup program (like some of [these here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)) and not just a simple synchronization program?!?

Comment: There are different reasons, like being able to access the backup from any computer, and because it takes just one click and a few seconds, but mainly because I love simple and flawless things :) I also make disk images once every 2 or 3 month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `--delete` option can lead to some unwanted destructive results if you are unaware of the background. For example, if the source becomes empty then all the existing files at the destination will be removed or if some files are removed from source then those files will be removed from destination too.

> What happens if my hard drive gets corrupted, and some files can not
>   be read anymore?

If `rsync` can not read the source, it would show a permission denied message and won't do anything further. So your existing files at the destination will be safe.

> Is there any scenario other than "me deleting the files on my hard
>   drive" that will lead to deletion of the files on the USB stick?

Unless your USB itself gets corrupted, no, there is no scenario where (you don't remove files from source, the hard drive and) the existing files on the USB will get deleted by `rsync` with `--delete` option.

**Test:**

```
% ls -1 source dest
dest:

source:
foo

% rsync -av --delete source/ dest
sending incremental file list
./
foo

sent 143 bytes  received 38 bytes  362.00 bytes/sec
total size is 16  speedup is 0.09

% ls -1 source dest              
dest:
foo

source:
foo

% chmod 000 source 

% rsync -av --delete source/ dest
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/source" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]

% ls -1 source dest              
dest:
foo
ls: cannot open directory source: Permission denied
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Do you have a reference for "If rsync can not read..", or is there an easy way to verify that?

Comment: @alain Please check my edits..

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I also tried with `chmod 000 source/foo` to be sure, and foo is still in dest.

Comment: @alain If you have `000` in a directory, no one can read the files inside that because directory contains the mapping between filename-inode of all files inside that directory..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; I tried with an unchanged `source` dir and just changed the permissions of the `foo` file. Is this correct to simulate an unreadable file in a readable dir?

Comment: @alain sorry i misunderstood....i thought you have done `chmod 000 source` before doing `chmod 000 source/foo` ....yeah, you are right..

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to corruption and deletion concerns is to employ a proper backup procedure.  Rotate a series of three (or more) USB thumbdrives, using the eldest 'backup' as the plugged in stick when you run this command once every week.  This way if you catch the corruption before you cycle through your USB drives, you can recover from it.  This is known as FIFO (First In, First Out).

There are other, more complicated schemes out there, all of which are compatible with your backup method.  A primer on some of these is available on Wikipedia at the following link:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme
```

Comment: I think I will make a rotation scheme with weekday folders on the USB drive, if there is enough space, because this will help if I want to recover a file that I deleted.

Comment: Another thing you might wish to consider (if you upgrade from USB drives to a large external hard drive) is using version control software.  You 'commit' your changes and it tracks the lifetime of the files in question (neatly avoiding the 'what if' for corruption and deletion as well as providing a way to recall any of the past versions as necessary).  A summary of this approach (though they don't touch on the use of backing up a machine in this fashion) can be found here --- http://biz30.timedoctor.com/git-mecurial-and-cvs-comparison-of-svn-software/